# Saving an XML file with a specific encoding without adding the tag in the opening line

Tags: c#, xml, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I've been writing a program that edits an XML file but I've run into a problem with the target program not correctly identifying the XML file when I'm done with it.

I've identified the problem as an encoding problem, as the program the XML files are intended for use Unicode encoding and my Visual Studio automatically saves things in UTF8. I've found answer that allow me to save in Unicode format, but Visual studio always adds an encoding tag to the first line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

Because of this, the program still doesnt read it. If I remove the encoding part manually, it works. I've searched for workarounds but I always end up with either UTF 8 format or with the encoding tag. The code I'm currently working with to find a solution is:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\Chem32\1\Methods\C1C4.M\Agilent\GC78901.RapidControl.MethodXML.xml");

using (StreamWriter output =
new StreamWriter(new FileStream(@"C:\Chem32\1\Methods\C1C4.M\Agilent\GC78901.RapidControl.MethodXML.xml", FileMode.Open), Encoding.Unicode))
{
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Encoding = Encoding.Unicode };
      using (XmlWriter xmlWriter =
          XmlWriter.Create(output, settings))
    {
        doc.Save(xmlWriter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've identified the problem as an encoding problem, as the program the XML files are intended for use Unicode encoding

By “Unicode encoding” I assume you mean Microsoft's misleading terminology for the UTF-16LE encoding.

For what it's worth a program that only reads XML byte streams if they are encoded in UTF-16LE is non-conformant with the XML 1.0 specification, as is refusing to accept an `<?xml` declaration. It would be great if you had access to that program to fix it.

> Visual studio always adds an encoding tag to the first line

You can add `OmitXmlDeclaration` to the XmlWriter settings to avoid that.

Also, you can skip creating your own StreamWriter and pass the Stream directly to XmlWriter. This is usually the better thing as it lets XmlWriter take care of byte encoding issues. Also in this case you could skip the stream as well since there is a shortcut for using the filename. eg

```
var path = @"C:\Chem32\1\Methods\C1C4.M\Agilent\GC78901.RapidControl.MethodXML.xml";
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Encoding=Encoding.Unicode, OmitXmlDeclaration = true };

using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(path, settings)) {
    doc.Save(writer);
}
```

ETA:

> That also removes the  tag and the target program requires this tag

aieee! This crazy software is so far from being a conformant XML processor. If you really have to conform to its absurd whims you could try adding an XML declaration yourself before the document, eg something like

```
var declaration = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";
var prolog = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(declaration);

using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
    stream.Write(prolog, 0, prolog.Length);
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings)) {
        doc.Save(writer);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried using OmitXMLDeclaration, but that also removes the <?xml version="1.0?> tag and the target program requires this tag. In the future I will try to use your method of calling the XMLwriter.

Comment: Okay I'm going to try this last bit you offered. Unfortunately, I absolutely have to conform to the software, considering it's not our own software. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It works in the program now finally! But the problem is now the XML file is not formatted as everything is on a single line. Is there a way to solve this?